# US Refugee Travel Document from JFK to Sri-Lanka

Tags: visas, international-travel, transit-visas, refugees, sri-lanka

ASAP! I’m writing this now and after 8hrs my flight to Sri-Lanka via Dubai.  My situation is: I'm granted asylum recently got RTD and now going to Sri-Lanka via Dubai from New-York. My question is

1) do I need have a visa?

2) There’s any custom/border problems in Dubai? Sri-Lanka?

3) Should I use only RTD for whole trip? (I still have valid citizen from my native country) or I have to use my passport?

Please help me?

Comment: What is your citizenship and residence status? Do you have an ETA for Sri Lanka? http://www.immigration.gov.lk/web/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=151&Itemid=196&lang=en

Comment: [Using your passport can invalidate your refugee status](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/108371/as-an-asylee-can-i-use-my-passport-instead-of-my-us-re-entry-permit). But Dubai does not accept refugee travel documents at all as far as I can tell. And you will need a physical visa for Sri Lanka regardless, I believe. You need to cancel this trip.

Comment: If you are a national of Sri Lanka, *do not travel there*. Timatic has a warning that your refugee travel document may be seized at the border. Of course, you might also be seized...

Comment: @MJeffryes UAE does not allow refugee travel document holders to enter, but as far as I have been able to determine they can still transit airside.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify questions. Putting on hold for now.