# My national passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, refugees, us-residents

I am a US asylee, and I have green card and USA travel document. I want to travel to UAE , and since UAE doesn't accept travel document can I use my national passport?

Comment: This is an extremely bad idea. Read this: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/108371/as-an-asylee-can-i-use-my-passport-instead-of-my-us-re-entry-permit

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate.  This person is NOT planning to go back to their country of citizenship but to a 3rd country, which is what the apparent duplicate question was asking!

Comment: Yes, the destination is different but the  _use_ of the refugee travel document is the same. A similar analysis applies: use of the passport implies submission to the authority of the persecuting state. It's still a bad idea.

Comment: @David furthermore, if the traveler is refused entry or deported, it will be much more difficult to avoid being sent to the persecuting state having entered with its passport.

Comment: this is not a "travel" question, it is an obscure law question at best

Comment: Think about it.  If you travel somewhere and you are refused entry, you are forcibly removed from the country.  Wher are you sent back to? *Where you came from?* Oh no, they might refuse you! You are sent to a place who cannot refuse you.  **The country that issued your passport**. Flying on country X passport always has a chance of being sent to country X.  That is why flying on that passport is the same as saying you don't fear your country.

Answer (score 12):

If you are still a citizen of your country or origjn you can still technically use its passport.

However you should be aware that if you have asylum in the United States that is because you have convinced the US that your country of origin is persecuting you and that you need to be protected from them. Using a passport supplied by them could be seen as putting yourself back under the protection of the people persecuting you. **This could result in loss of your asylum status, including loss of your green card.**

You should not use your original passport unless you are willing to lose your asylum status. If you absolutely have to go somewhere that needs it, consult an immigration lawyer before you do so.