# Does a Austrian refugee passport holder need a visa to enter Azerbaijan?

Tags: visas, refugees, azerbaijan

Hi am from Pakistan i have a refugee passport can i travel to Azerbaijani with out visa? Can i get visa on arrival?
Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

You will not be able to enter Azerbaijan without a visa nor receive one upon arrival.

Holders of regular Austrian passports, as well as holders of regular Pakistani passports, are eligible to apply for [an electronic visa ("asan viza")](https://evisa.gov.az/en/) which can be done online for US$20 and in only a few days. So if you have, or can readily get, either of those documents, this would be an easy option. Do note that using a Pakistani passport in this way [may jeopardize your refugee status](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/108371/as-an-asylee-can-i-use-my-passport-instead-of-my-us-re-entry-permit) and you should not take this option without serious consideration and consultation with the relevant Austrian authorities.

However, if the only travel document available to you is the Austrian refugee passport, you are not eligible to use the electronic visa system. Instead, you must [apply for a visa at the Azerbaijani embassy in Vienna](https://vienna.mfa.gov.az/en/content/74/information-for-visa-obtaining-and-required-documents).

Comment: Using your home country (Pakistani) passport in any fashion can pose a **serious risk** to your status as an asylum-seeker, and may cause your asylum status to be revoked. You should seek legal advice from an attorney or solicitor in Austria before you use your Pakistan passport. Please review [this question and answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/108371/as-an-asylee-can-i-use-my-passport-instead-of-my-us-re-entry-permit/108372#108372).

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica thank you, I've edited my answer to clarify.